# How to override the url that the create button routes to on a resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I would like to know how to override the url that the create resource button routes to, on a resource listing page?

Comment: simple create a route with create function in laravel route. e.g.

`Route::get('/create',[App/Http/Controllers/Controller::class,'create']);`